# How can a Blackberry app send push notifications to both BIS and BES users?

Tags: web-applications, blackberry, push-notification

I've been tearing what's left of my hair out for days trying to wrap up the Blackberry version of a mobile app I am producing.  Although other parts of BB dev have been frustrating, nothing compares to implementing push notifications.

I have read all of the PDFs and other doc pages RIM provides about push notifications, but it seems like they are purposely vague about all the important details.  There are pages and pages in every PDF trying to sell you on their Push Plus service, and then a sentence or two about the actually important details.  I have also looked at their scant few samples, but they are all really contrived and don't really help.

The one question (which seems to me like it would be a pretty common one for mobile devs) that I can't get an answer to would be this:

Is it possible to write a public app for Blackberry -- a normal persons app not some crazy company specific stuff -- that both BIS and BES (personal and corporate) users can both install and use with push notifications?

It would seem that the answer is yes, Facebook uses push notifications and I would certainly assume both kinds of users can use Facebook -- but the docs are as clear as mud about how you would go about making a public app that can send notifications to BES users.

This is a problem I have to solve if at all possible, so if it means I have to write some special component I'll do it, but I don't know if it's even possible.

I use Urban Airship to do notifications for iOS and Android (both of which were about 1000x more pleasant to implement than BB so far), but their documentation says they don't support BES users (at all).

I keep hoping to find the magical document that clearly lays out how all this stuff works, but I don't think it's out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many BES users also have BIS, so using the standard BlackBerry push service should cover both sets of users.

To use BES push specifically, I think you would need to setup code with each BES administrator you want to work with -- not a tenable approach.